# Поскажите какие операторы нужно использовать! Я попробовал и не получяется

Tags: c++

Число называется «совершенным», если оно равно сумме его делителей, меньших его. Например, n = 28 является идеальным числом, потому что 28 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14. Напишите программу, которая проверяет, является ли число n или не совершенным. Я добавил код попробовать [image: IMG]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: `n%1` - это остаток от деления числа n на 1. Любое число делится на 1 без остатка. поэтому проверка на это бессмысленна. Следует проверять делимость на разные делители

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать у себя в коде, но для решения задачи нужен один цикл по всем делителям числа. Получив очередной делитель, добавляем его в сумму. Если после выполнения цикла сумма равна числу, то число совершенное. Чтобы проверить, является ли число делителем, используйте проверку `num % den == 0`.